# C#: Canceling BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, controls

I'm trying to have a control do the following:

On the first click start to display text: one character every 30ms.
On the second click cancel the process and immediately display the full text.

This is the method that I pass to the control via BeginInvoke():

```
DBX_Dialogue.running = true;
for (int i = 0; i < line.text.Length; i++)
{
    Text += line.text[i];
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    if (DBX_Dialogue.cancel)
    {
        Text = line.text;
        DBX_Dialogue.running = false;
        break;
    }
}
DBX_Dialogue.running = false;
```

In the main window's OnClick() method I do this:

```
if (DBX_Dialogue.running)
{
    DBX_Dialogue.cancel = true;
    return;
}
else
{
    DelWrite delWrite = WriteLine;
    DBX_Dialogue.BeginInvoke(delWrite);
}
```

However, DBX_Dialogue.cancel is never being set to true, so I suppose my method isn't actually running asynchronously - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! Is the way I handled this okay or is there some better way? I marked my method as async and then used this line: await Task.Delay(30);

Comment: If you wait 30 seconds in a loop (on a background thread, using `Thread.Sleep`, `await Task.Delay` or using a WinForms timer, you still aren't going to get responsive behavior.  Look at your code.  If someone sets `DBX_Dialogue.cancel` right after your last poll, it will be 30 seconds before you see it.  Consider making the poll time much faster (say 250 ms) and loop 4x30 times to mark off your 30 seconds, or create more elaborate mechanism (likely using `WaitHandle.WaitAny` or `Task.WaitAny`) to signal cancellation.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that the `Control.BeginInvoke()` method that you're calling, invokes the delegate on the UI thread. Once the delegate has been invoked, the UI thread won't be available to execute other code until that delegate's target has finished executing.

So if the `OnClick()` method you refer to is supposed to be handling a click event in a control owned by that UI thread, that event handler can't execute, because the UI thread is stuck working on the delegate invocation.

There is another `BeginInvoke()` method that's defined for any delegate type. That one will queue the delegate invocation on the thread pool. Possibly that's the one you meant to call instead? That would look something like this:

```cs
    delWrite.BeginInvoke();
```

Of course, when you do that you will run into problems access the UI objects from the thread pool thread. Then you'll need to use `Control.Invoke()` there, just for those specific statements. There are lots of questions with answers on the site that discuss that technique.

Your question is lacking a lot of detail that would help the rest of us understand the full scenario and provide better advice. The fact is, the basic structure of the code looks suspect and there is almost certainly a better approach that wouldn't involve calling any `BeginInvoke()` method. But it's impossible to know exactly what that would look like without more details. You can look into things like the Task Parallel Library and `async`/`await` for the modern approaches to coordinating asynchronous work with the UI thread.

Here's a wild guess as to what an alternative, modern implementation of what you're trying to do would look like:

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource tcs;

async Task Run(CancellationToken token)
{
    DBX_Dialogue.running = true;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.text.Length; i++)
        {
            Text += line.text[i];
            await Task.Delay(30, token);
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCancelledException)
    {
        Text = line.text;
    }
    finally
    {
        DBX_Dialogue.running = false;
    }
}

void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DBX_Dialogue.running)
    {
        this.tcs.Cancel();
        this.tcs.Dispose();
        this.tcs = null;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        this.tcs = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _ = Run(tcs.Token);
    }
}
```

There's no code sample to start with, so I haven't bothered compiling the above, never mind actually testing it. It may require some fiddling to get it to work just like you want. But that's the basic idea.

Comment: I should have clarified that the OnClick() in question belongs to the main window so it isn't blocked while the control does its thing. I'll have a look at and try out some alternatives. Since I didn't realize the problem was the Thread.sleep() command I may have overcomplicated things.

Comment: _"OnClick() in question belongs to the main window so it isn't blocked while the control does its thing"_ -- there's only one thread. Or at least, there ought to be only one thread. That there are multiple controls involved doesn't change that. A `BeginInvoke()` from any control will block (when the delegate runs) _all_ controls owned by the same thread.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand why replacing Thread.Sleep(30) with await Task.Delay(30) did the trick.

Comment: Because `Thread.Sleep(30)` blocks the thread, while `await Task.Delay(30)` does not.